# Convert scanned pdf to searchable pdf using php

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdf, searchable

I have scanned pdf file and I need to convert this scanned pdf file to searchable pdf file using php. I searched for this and found pdfocr tool.

When I run the following command in terminal it works fine:

```
pdfocr -i input.pdf -o output.pdf
```

But when I run following command in php code its not giving any error but also not converting to searchable pdf file:

```
$output = shell_exec("pdfocr -i input.pdf -o output.pdf");
```

Is something wrong with shell_exec command of php or anything else wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First see if your tool and the input file are present when you execute a command: `$output = \`ls -al\`; echo "<pre>$output</pre>";`.

Comment: @kiko-software Yes, I installed pdfocr in my laptop and giving same input file path in both(terminal cmd and shell exec cmd). And shell_exec are working fine for other ubuntu commands.

Comment: So you've done my test and you see the two files you need. That's good. Next you have to look at permissions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @kiko-software I have checked permission of "/var/www/projectname/uploads/" folder. It's showing "drwxrwxrwx 2". I don't think that its permission issue because in the same folder I am converting any doc file to pdf file using shell_exec cmd.